# rundeck config value in one of the options inside job using api

Tags: api, rundeck

I have rundeck 2.6.11 and I'm trying to config value in one of the options inside job using api

I already have valit token and I can perform get uri requests 
for example:

```
curl --noproxy -x GET http://rundeck.domain.com:4440/api/18/projects?authtoken=##########
```

And I can get the data

But I couldn't find any option to set the value to one of the options in a job

I also tried this kb http://rundeck.org/docs/api/ but I didn't find a solution for my case

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rundeck API doesn't have direct implementation for update job options, but you can update a job by updating the job definition file.

1. **Export the job definition** via

   `GET /api/1/job/[ID]`

   You can specify `format=xml` or `format=yaml`

   [Rundeck - Exporting Jobs](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/#exporting-jobs)
2. **Update the option in the job definition** using your preferred programming language.
3. **Import the job definition you've updated** via

   `POST /api/1/project/[PROJECT]/jobs/import`

   By default the `uuidOption` is set to `preserve`, which means you are updating an existing with same UUID

   [Rundeck - Importing Jobs](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/#importing-jobs)